# Combine GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SAMPLE DATA

```
userid         email_address               login_name       name                Title       org            phone_number_com
=============  ==========================  ===============  ==================  ==========  =============  ===================
1192           Steve.Jobs@apple.com        sjobs            Steve Jobs          CEO         Apple          N/A
1274           Steve.Jobs@apple.com        sjobs            Steve Jobs          CFO         Apple          697-4686
1192           Steven.jobs@apple.com       sjobs            Steven jobs         CEO         Apple          604-7126
1885           Bill.Gates@microsoft.com    bgates           Bill Gates          CEO         Microsoft      604-7114
1920           Bill.Gates@microsoft.com    bgates           William Gates       CTR         Microsoft      604-7247
1951           Warren.Buffet@hp.com        wbuffet          Warren Buffet       CEO         HP             614-9141
1954           Warren.Buffet@hp.com        wbuffet          W. Buffet           COO         HP             614-7589
1951           Warren.Buffet@xerox.com     wbuffet          Warren S Buffet     CIO         Xerox          614-8874
1956           Mark.Zuckerberg@fb.com      mzuck            Mark  Zuckerberg    CEO         FB             614-8295
```

QUERY

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (
        SELECT userid, name, login_name, email_address, phone_number_com,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [login_name] ORDER BY login_name) Num_Duplicates
        FROM web_user
    ) as Rows
WHERE Num_Duplicates > 1
```

This is my first post, hopefully I am following all the procedures. I get a result set which displays the 2nd and 3rd rows which are duplicated. I am trying to `GROUP BY` `login_name` and only display the the row with the highest `Num_Duplicates`. If a `login_name` has a `Num_Duplicates` of 2 and 3, to only display the row with 3. I hope this makes sense! Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide.

THESE ARE THE RESULTS I WOULD LIKE THE QUERY TO OUTPUT:

```
userid  | email_address | login_name    | name  | Title | org   phone_number_com    | Num_Duplicates       
1192    | Steve.Jobs@apple.com  | sjobs | Steve Jobs    | CEO   | Apple |   N/A | 3      
1885    | Bill.Gates@microsoft.com  | bgates    | Bill Gates    | CEO   | Microsoft | 604-7114  | 2       
1951    | Warren.Buffet@hp.com  | wbuffet   | Warren Buffet | CEO   | HP    | 614-9149  | 3
```

Comment: why do you need row number?

Comment: Would you add your desired result?

Comment: Why only display the third one?    You're grouping AND ordering by login_name, which means the order within each group is arbitrary and can differ each time you execute.   So 1, 2, 3.. they're all the same.   Why only show 3?   Why not only show 2 or only show 1?

Comment: lets back up and find out what you're after.  Are you simply after a list of all "Duplicates based on login_name" and display the fields from anyone one of the 3 records?

Comment: Sorry, Yes I am after all the duplicated  login_name's and only need to display a field from any of the records, whether is it 2 or 3.

Comment: userid         email_address               login_name       name                Title       org            phone_number_com    Num_Duplicates
1192           Steve.Jobs@apple.com        sjobs            Steve Jobs          CEO         Apple          N/A                 3
1885           Bill.Gates@microsoft.com    bgates           Bill Gates          CEO         Microsoft      604-7114            2
1951           Warren.Buffet@hp.com        wbuffet          Warren Buffet       CEO         HP             614-9141            3

Comment: How can a given value of `login_name` have more than one value in `num_duplicates`? It can't be both 2 and 3; it can only be 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you would group by the login name first to get the number of duplicates:

```
SELECT login_name, COUNT(*) AS num_duplicates
  FROM web_user
 GROUP BY login_name
```

Here you can either use a subquery with `ROW_NUMBER()` (though I would recommend using `RANK()` in case of ties) or you can just use the aggregate in the window function:

```
SELECT login_name, COUNT(*) AS num_duplicates
     , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rn
  FROM web_user
 GROUP BY login_name;
```

then put this in a subquery to get only the `login_name` with the most duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT login_name, COUNT(*) AS num_duplicates
         , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC ) AS rn
      FROM web_user
     GROUP BY login_name
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

**UPDATE per OP's comments, question edits:**

```
SELECT userid, name, login_name, email_address, phone_number_com, num_duplicates
  FROM (
    SELECT userid, name, login_name, email_address, phone_number_com
         , COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY login_name ) AS num_duplicates
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY login_name ORDER BY userid ) AS rn
      FROM web_user
) WHERE num_duplicates > 1 AND rn = 1;
```

What I'm doing above is using `COUNT(*)` as a window function; partitioning by `login_name` will get the count for each login name. I'm also partitioning by `login_name` to get for `ROW_NUMBER()` and ordering by `userid` so that I can return the minimum value (which you seem to be doing in your desired output).

Comment: I would have added HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 condition there, so you really know these are duplicates

Comment: based on OP's text, I'm pretty sure that's not what Ariel wants.

Comment: David, I began with the following query:

Comment: SELECT login_name, COUNT(1) AS Num_Duplicates
FROM web_user
GROUP BY login_name
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC                                                           The problem I ran into is that I need to display userid, name, login_name, email_address, phone_number_com in the results.

Comment: @Ariel, I'm sorry, but I am really not following you.

Comment: @David, I initially wrote the first query you provided but in the output result, I need to include the userid, name, login_name, email_address, phone_number, and num_duplicates. The queries you provided output the login_name and num_duplicates only.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - from your description is sounds like you simply want something like this (off the top of my head):

```
SELECT login_name, email_address 
FROM web_user
GROUP BY login_name, email_address
HAVING count(*) > 2
```

Comment: In my results, I need to return with userid, name, login_name, email_address, phone_number_com.

Comment: Just add those as needed -- e.g. `login_name, email_address, MAX(phone_number)`, and so on.

Comment: ISE, If I GROUP BY all the columns I am selecting it will give me an inaccurate result. I need to GROUP BY only login_name and display the other fields I am selecting (e.g. userid, name, login_name, email_address, phone_number_com)

Comment: As long as you realize you can only have one of those other field values per group, even if there are more in the data, you can group on just one column and select the rest of the columns with MIN or MAX as I show above.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you need.

The `ROW_NUMBER` window function is used to identify the first row for a login_name.

The `COUNT` window function is used to count the number of rows per login_name.

The outer query then restricts the results to those login_name that have more than 1 row and only the first row for each login_name is returned.

```
DECLARE @users TABLE
(
    userid              int
    , email_address     varchar(100)
    , login_name        varchar(100)
    , name              varchar(100)
    , title             varchar(100)
    , org               varchar(100)
    , phone_number_com  varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @users
VALUES
(1192, 'Steve.Jobs@apple.com', 'sjobs', 'Steve Jobs', 'CEO', 'Apple', 'N/A')
, (1274, 'Steve.Jobs@apple.com', 'sjobs', 'Steve Jobs', 'CFO', 'Apple', '697-4686')
, (1192, 'Steven.jobs@apple.com', 'sjobs', 'Steven jobs', 'CEO', 'Apple', '604-7126')
, (1885, 'Bill.Gates@microsoft.com', 'bgates', 'Bill Gates', 'CEO', 'Microsoft', '604-7114')
, (1920, 'Bill.Gates@microsoft.com', 'bgates', 'William Gates', 'CTR', 'Microsoft', '604-7247')
, (1951, 'Warren.Buffet@hp.com', 'wbuffet', 'Warren Buffet', 'CEO', 'HP', '614-9141')
, (1954, 'Warren.Buffet@hp.com', 'wbuffet', 'W. Buffet', 'COO', 'HP', '614-7589')
, (1951, 'Warren.Buffet@xerox.com', 'wbuffet', 'Warren S Buffet', 'CIO', 'Xerox', '614-8874')
, (1956, 'Mark.Zuckerberg@fb.com', 'mzuck', 'Mark Zuckerberg', 'CEO', 'FB', '614-8295')
;

WITH LoginWithWindowFunction AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY login_name ORDER BY userid) AS LoginOrder
        , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY login_name) AS Num_Duplicates

    FROM
        @users
)

SELECT
    userid
    , email_address
    , login_name
    , name
    , title
    , org
    , phone_number_com
    , Num_Duplicates

FROM
    LoginWithWindowFunction

WHERE
    LoginOrder = 1
    AND Num_Duplicates > 1

ORDER BY
    userid
```